# Copy file along with creating directory

Tags: r, file-copying, create-directory

I have a file in the directory as /a/b/c/xxxxx.sql

I have anorther directory /a/b/d, having no further sub directories

How should I copy xxxxx.sql into /a/b/d, to have the new file with directory as /a/b/d/c/xxxxx.sql , in 1 command